# retrieve data from Mysql to ListView Javafx

Tags: mysql, listview, javafx, observablelist

how I can retrieve data from database in ListView. I have 3 column in the table (title, description, date). I want retrieve title in ListView, and then by clicking on title get description(textarea) and date(label). I know that need create ObservableList to display the items. But all my attemps was unsuccessful. I'm new in java, could somebody help me resolve this issue, write a links, tutorials, etc. Thanks.
[Scene builder window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zk8d9.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, this question is far too broad for this site. Did you take the [tour[ yet?  Also, it will help you to read the [ask] article before posting a question here. Questions need to be very specific and detailed, and pertaining to a single issue you're having.

Answer (score 0):

I find how to resolve my issue instead of ListView I can use TableView with ObservableList. So, this question is answered. If somebody want to know how it works, please asking me.